# Rest API by Swift in IOS is not executed

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am using REST API to get data from server using swift 2. When I call the function below, something happens, and the `func getAllServiceName(data :NSData)` is not executed. I tried many things but I did not have success.

```
func getServiceName () {
    let urlServiceName = NSURL(string: "urllinkOfMe")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: urlServiceName!)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
        self.getAllServiceName(data!)
    }
}

func getAllServiceName(data :NSData)
{
    let dictServicename: NSDictionary!=(try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary

    if(dictServicename["data"] != nil){
        let dataTable :NSArray = dictServicename.valueForKey("data") as! NSArray
        for var i = 0 ; i < dataTable.count ; i++
        {
            //pickOptionVas.addObject(dataTable[i].valueForKey("serviceName")!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which method you use "POST" or "GET"? and running on which iOS version?

Comment: I use method GET, and iOS v9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you used to get data from server by calling API:

```
func getServiceName () {

    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    let urlServiceName = NSURL(string: "http://188.166.232.101:1000/hs/vasService/getServiceName")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: urlServiceName!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    let postTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        print(data)
    })
    //This is necessary
    postTask.resume()
}
```

Go for the above code and let me know you are getting the data or not!

[image]

Comment: many thank for you.
But not success, when my program run to "session.dataTaskWithRequest.."
It don't run to function, it overlook "self.getAllServiceName(data!)"

Comment: NOT Possible, have you put debug under this function? `getAllServiceName`

Comment: Can I see you link URL?

Comment: function getAllServiceName is not call

Comment: @HảiNguyễnHoàng Check the commented answer! I get the data

Comment: @HảiNguyễnHoàng This one line making problem! `postTask.resume()`

Comment: I try, but not success

Comment: print(data) is not run by program

Answer (score 0):

What's the response code? if you get 500 perhaps something wrong with your request parameter or your REST API is not implemented correctly.

Comment: I think rest API don't execute correctly. but i can't fix it, you can help me?